# Redux State Updates but table does not update (even with pure & immutable state update)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

i have been looking around for an answer to my problem and have found a lot about not changing the pre-existing redux state object in the reducer. My issue is that i seem to be changing my state okay (according to the devtools and console logs) but for some reason my table does not re-render. Here is some devtools output which shows that somehow the *props* have been updated but not the *state*: [devtools component props/state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5ooo.jpg). My question is *why* is it that my table does not fill with data when it seems as if my redux store has the needed data?

This is what the empty table looks like: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81gx7.jpg)

This is my component class:

```
class Overview extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
this.props.getOverviewData();
}

render() {
const { overview } = this.props;
console.log(overview);
return (
  <div className={this.props.classes.divPadding}>
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem lg={3} sm={4} xs={12}>
        <Typography
          className={this.site_name}
          variant="h6"
          color="textSecondary"
        >
          photoboothrental.co
        </Typography>
      </GridItem>

      <GridItem xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Card className={this.props.classes.fixedHeight}>
          <CardHeader color="success" stats icon>
            <CardIcon color="success">
              <TimelineIcon />
            </CardIcon>
            <p className={this.props.classes.cardCategory}>Average Rank</p>
            <h2 className={this.props.classes.cardTitle}>
              {/* {(
                overviewState.rows.reduce((total, row) => {
                  return total + row.last_data.rank;
                }, 0) / overviewState.rows.length
              ).toFixed(2)} */}
              {overview.latest_agg_rank}
            </h2>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardFooter stats>
            <div className={this.props.classes.stats}>
              <DateRange />
              Last Updated: 17/01/2020
            </div>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Card className={this.props.classes.fixedHeight}>
          <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
            <CardIcon color="danger">
              <ArrowDownwardIcon />
            </CardIcon>
            <p className={this.props.classes.cardCategory}>
              Last {overview.last_x_days} Days Overall Up/Down
            </p>
            <h2 className={this.props.classes.cardTitle}>
              {overview.last_x_days_aggr_rank}
            </h2>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardFooter stats>
            <div className={this.props.classes.stats}>
              <DateRange />
              Last Updated: 17/01/2020
            </div>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Card className={this.props.classes.fixedHeight}>
          <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
            {/* <CardIcon color="danger">
              <ArrowDownwardIcon />
            </CardIcon> */}
            <p className={this.props.classes.cardCategory}>
              Last {overview.last_x_days} Days Keyword Count
            </p>
            <h2 className={this.props.classes.cardTitle}>
              {overview.last_x_days_num_keywords}
            </h2>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardFooter stats>
            <div className={this.props.classes.stats}>
              <DateRange />
              Last Updated: 17/01/2020
            </div>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem xs={12}>
        <TableDynamic
          title={"Keyword List"}
          data={overview.data}
          columns={overview.columns}
        />
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  </div>
);
}
Overview.propTypes = {
  getOverviewData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  overview: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ overview: state.rankTrackerOverview });

export default withStyles(styles)(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getOverviewData
  })(Overview)
);
```

My action is simply an ajax request to a node.js backend:

```
export const getOverviewData = () => dispatch => {
  axios.get("/api/data/get_overview").then(res => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_OVERVIEW,
      payload: res.data
    });
  });
};
```

I am console logging the response from my backend which looks something like this:

[backend form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6BJD.jpg)

my reducer looks like this with *initState* having the data property initialised to an empty array []:

```
const rankTrackerOverviewReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_OVERVIEW:
      const new_data = [
        ...state.data,
        ...action.payload.map(keyword => {
          return [
            keyword._id.replace(/\+/g, " "),
            keyword.latest_rank,
            keyword.avg_rank,
            keyword.best_rank,
            keyword.worst_rank
          ];
        })
      ];
      return {
        ...state,
        data: new_data
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rankTrackerOverviewReducer;
```

and i have combined my reducer in anticipation for the creation of others. I am fairly new to Javascript/Redux etc. and am skeptical that this is anything but some immutability issue that i am not catching. Hopefully someone can provide me with some tips!! Thankyou very much.

Here is the output to my `console.log(overview)` Matt:

[image: console log output]

Comment: What does your console.log(overview) look like?

Comment: @MattSugden I have edited my post to include a link to the console.log(overview) output!

Comment: So from the looks of it, your component gets rendered twice, once with no data and once with some data. Just above your table component, can you put <div>{overview.data.length}</div>, or something similar. Does the number change from 0 to 3? I'm just trying to narrow the issue down the table component itself, and not this component.

Comment: @MattSugden yeah i added a <div> with what you wanted to test and it does change from 0 to 3

Comment: So that's telling me the issue is in your table. Is that component your own or is it a plugin? Are you sure the data is in the correct format? Do you get console errors from the component?

Comment: @MattSugden I have discovered my problem. I forgot i wrapped the table component in a custom table component i created and didn't provide a "ComponentDidUpdate" lifecycle method. So when the props for the custom component updated, it didn't update the state which was local to it. (i will probably change this but its a work in progress.) i hope this makes sense and thankyou for all your help.